# Drush destination command not recognising

Tags: drush, backups

I'm able to see the destinations by using the 'bam-destinations' command and below is my script to get an entire site backup from a ftp destination (ID of this destination is 'ftp_destination' and I have entered ftp details through BAM module frontend).

```
drush archive-dump default http://www.example.com/ --destination=ftp_destination
```

For some reason it's not uploading in to the ftp location but just creates a backup called 'ftp_destination' in my local PC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [drush documentation here](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-7x/archive/archive-dump).
There's no mention of ftp, the backup archive is saved locally. If you want to ftp your archive somewhere you will have to handle it separately, archive-dump will not do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for that rtome :)

What could be a starting point to do a research in connecting to ftp server using the command prompt?

Comment: No, I ment create a shell script, put ypur drush command there and then put an ftp (or scp) command to transfer your file to your other machine. Check this thread   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894347/how-to-upload-ftp-files-to-server-in-a-bash-script for an example.